# How to get a div popup by clicking submit button using fancy box / light box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, fancybox, lightbox

my mark up

```
<div class="popup bg-white"><!--pop up box begins-->
            <a href="" class="close-btn fr center_text">
                <b class="small-font">X</b>
                <span>CLOSE</span>
            </a>
            <div class="popup-title medium_18 font-bold">Please edit your details below:</div>
            <div class="clearfix">  
                <input type="text" class="input_box" value="" name="" placeholder="Miss Rachael Short" size="49" />
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix">
                <input type="text" class="input_box" value="" name="" placeholder="Industrial Way" size="49" />
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix">  
                <input type="text" class="input_box" value="" name="" placeholder="Bath" size="49" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">  
                <input type="text" class="input_box" value="" name="" placeholder="Somerset" size="49" />
            </div>  
            <div class="clearfix">  
                <input type="text" class="input_box" value="" name="" placeholder="BA2 8SF" size="49" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-common fr btn-big auto_width" value="submit" type="submit" name="submit">EDIT</button>
        </div><!--pop up box ends-->
```

Button `<button class="btn btn-common fl btn-myacc auto_width" value="submit" 
type="submit" name="submit">EDIT</button>`

[UPDATE]
css `.popup { visiblity: hidden }`

I need to pop up that div `popup` when clicking the EDIT button.

How can I rite the JS code for that?
My site has [fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox) script in the header.

Comment: Add an onclick="show_dialog()" to your button??

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your button outside popup div, give a unique ID to popup div and a class to your button and setup your fancybox code accordingly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/9361/)

HTML

```
<div id="popupID" class="popup bg-white"><!--pop up box begins-->
        <!-- rest of the html -->    
</div><!--pop up box ends-->

<button class="fancybox btn btn-common fr btn-big auto_width" value="submit" type="submit" name="submit">EDIT</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'href' : '#popupID'
});
```

Comment: but how to change the fancy box width and height? it take auto for height and 130px for width automatically.. I've tried `<script>
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({'href' : '#popupID',
  'width'  : 600, 'height' : 600
  });
 </script>` but not working

Comment: give width and height to .popup div in the css

Comment: I've removed `position: absolute` in .popup and now it's fine. how to remove the overlay and the fancy box skin?

Comment: updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/9362/. Use fancybox classes to change css. You'll find a lot of helpful documentation here - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful